# How to Upload File to AWS S3 Bucket via pre signed URL in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading file to S3 bucket using S3 upload function in Node.js. The frontend is built on Angular. But now the client's requirement is that all uploads should direct to s3 bucket via a presigned URL. Does this because of any security concern? The Code that i am currently using to upload files to S3 Bucket is:

```
async function uploadFile(object){
//object param contains two properties 'image_data' and 'path'
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        var obj = object.image_data;
        var imageRemoteName = object.path+'/'+Date.now()+obj.name;
        AWS.config.update({
          accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY,
          secretAccessKey: SECRET_KEY,
          region: REGION
        })

        var s3 = new AWS.S3()
        s3.upload({
          Bucket: BUCKET,
          Body: obj.data,
          Key: imageRemoteName
        })
        .promise()
        .then(response => {
            console.log(`done! - `, response)
            resolve(response.Location)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('failed:', err)
        })

  })
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: How's it going? Are you still unclear what to do?

Answer (score -1):

Security wise it doesn't make a difference whether you call `upload` or first create a pre-signed URL, as long as the code you showed does not run within your Angular application, meaning on the client. In that case every client of your application has access to your AWS access key, and secret key. Still, swapping `upload` with a pre-signed URL won't solve the problem in this case. However, if you use a server such as [express](https://expressjs.com/) and that's where this code is running, you're basically fine.

AWS provides [instructions on how to upload objects using a pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). The basic steps are:

```js
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
const s3Client = new S3Client({ 
    accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_KEY,
    region: REGION 
});

/* ... */

const command = new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: BUCKET,
  Body: obj.data,
  Key: imageRemoteName
});

// upload image and return a new signed URL, 
// with expiration to download image, if needed. 
// Otherwise you can leave `signedUrl` unused.
const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
  expiresIn: 3600,
});
```